# C: How to read variables from a file

Tags: c

[image]

What is the best way to create a function that reads each part of a file like described in the following picture and saves it to arrays and integers, it must read and save the second part (above word_count): word; orientation; row; col; points; jogador until a number(Turn) is read.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Read a line with `fgets()`. Then use `sscanf()` to parse it according to the appropriate format.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried.  It helps us gauge what you know so we can give a useful answer.  For example, if you don't know about structures yet, giving you a solution using structures won't help you much.  If you don't know about dynamic memory allocation, showing a solution using `malloc()` et al won't help you much.  You need to show what you've tried so we can tell what will actually help you.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Thanks!

Comment: The best way.... hmm, maybe ask at SO and hope someone will do it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start by creating 3 struct's. One for people. One for words and one to aggregate the full structure. For the third, you will need to decide which arrays can be sized at compile time and which need to use malloc or calloc to allocate space for the people or word structures. 
Next write a function to populate a person from a one line string and one to populate a word from a one line string. You could use strchr to find the semicolons or for less error durability you might look at sscanf.
Finally write your loading function to read the file line by line detecting 'mode' changes by (strchr(line, ';') == -1), and calling the appropriate convert function. You can then return the aggregate structure as a pointer to a malloc'ed struct. 
Don't forget to write a function, that takes that pointer, to dispose of everything you malloc'ed so that a caller does not need to know your allocation details and can just say "get me one from that file" followed by "throw this away".
Unfortunately, C is unlike Java or C# in that the heavy lifting is not built in or covered by copious included libraries. You need to find libraries or write low level code yourself.
Good luck with you project.